# Where should I ask questions about reasoning (e.g. fallacies or arguments)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I got interested in fallacies and good reasoning in general. I started with reading discussions online and mostly tried to identify fallacies hoping it would help me to make better arguments myself by not falling into the same traps.

I still have a lot of problems identifying or making a good argument since good reasoning is actually much harder than I first thought.

Is there a Stack Exchange site best suited for asking questions about reasoning and get help with identifying fallacies, or getting help with building arguments?

I thought Philosophy Stack Exchange could fit but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought Philosophy Stack Exchange could fit

I agree; they already have [hundreds of questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallacies) about fallacies. Try to search for your question first, and if it hasn't been asked before check [How do I ask a good question?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in their help center. "Getting help with building arguments" sounds a bit vague, but with sufficient context it might work out for you.